# file_handle class - how can i use the file stream outside the class

Tags: c++

I want to write a file_handle class like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//===========================================================================
class File_handle {
    FILE* p;
    public:
    File_handle(const char* pp, const char* r) {
    p = fopen(pp, r);
    }
    File_handle(const std::string& s, const char* r) {
    p = fopen(s.c_str(), r);
    }
    ~File_handle() {
    if (p) 
    fclose(p);
    }
    // what is this ?????    i found it in stroustrups c++ on page 389
    // ---> Mark A
    operator FILE*() { return p;} 


    // I have tried something like this, but without any success
    // ---> Mark B
    //friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const File_handle&); 
};

//===========================================================================
int main() {
    const std::string filename("test.txt");
    File_handle fh(filename, "w");
    // doesn't work
    // fh << "hello\n";
    // *fh << "hello\n";
    // this works now
    File_handle fA("A.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fA, "say hello to A.txt");
    File_handle fB("B.txt", "w");
    fputs("say hello to B.txt", fB);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know, how I can use the file stream outside the class.
I have tried it with overloading the `operator<<`, how you can see in the code example above. (Indicated as: mark B in the code above.)

And I found the line `operator FILE*() { return p; }` in the book of Bjarne Stroustrup.
But which operator is overloaded in this line? (Indicated as: mark A)

Comment: You don't get magic for free. All you've done is wrap a `FILE*` to provide RAII for closing the file (something you can also [do with `unique_ptr`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4679)). Why don't you use `<fstream>`?

Comment: `FILE*`? This is C++. Act like it!

Comment: I found this example on a slide from the Keynote - Bjarne Stroustrup: c++11 Style.

Comment: And i wanted to give it a try. Thank u for your link Kerrek SB. Now it is clearer for me.

Comment: I saw it in the same keynote: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style at minute 30:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `std::fstream` instead of your `File_handle` class.

But if you need to specify some additional behaviour, you can derive your class from `std::fstream`. So this kind of solution could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class File_handle : public std::fstream
{
public:
    File_handle(const char* filename, _Openmode o) { open(filename, o); }
    ~File_handle() { close(); }
};

int main()
{
    File_handle fh("test.txt", std::ios::out);
    fh << "aa";
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This operator, "operator FILE*() { return p;}" is a cast operator.  It will be called implicitly whenever a File_handle object is passed to a function where it only expects a FILE* argument.  Even if this function was never overloaded with a version explicitly taking a File_handle object, it will transparently handle the object because the cast operator will be called used to convert from type File_handle into type FILE*.  Now, you can use your File_handle object with APIs that only know how to handle FILE* arguments. The transparent conversion gives your code a clean, familiar and easy-to-read look.  But sometimes the compiler decides to pick a different conversion function than the one you think should be used.  There are sume subtle rules about how the compiler chooses a conversion function for some particular situation.  If a lot of these implicit conversions are happening behind the scenes, problems can crop up that are very hard to debug -- even the writer of a class might be unaware of what is actually going on inside.

As for the "<<" operator...

I'll make an example class that implements an ostream-like  "<<" operator, but I'll completely leave out the standard C++ library -- it just uses raw C++ and the C Runtime.  I'm leaving it out in order to isolate the fundamental C++ from the library.  I'm not advocating for or against making a class like this -- I just want to clearly demonstrate this basic technique.

Inside File_handle's class definition block, I've added several overlads of File_handle::operator<<(x) -- you need to make a different version for each basic type, or at least each type you expect to handle.  The trick is to abuse the shift operator's semantics: these overloads all return a reference to the File_handle object itself.  So when you start an expression with an instance of File_handle on the left side, each time "<<" is evaluated, one of your overloads is called (chosen according to the type of the right-side argument) and then it evaluates to a reference to the same File_handle object. So the "<<" operator immediately following the first evaluation will again use the initial class instance for its left-side argument, but the right-side argument will be the next operand, the next one to the right of the initail evaluation. This is how an indefinite number of operands can be chained together with "<<", all processed from left to right, by a single instance of your class.

Pardon the compact style. I'm trying to keep the whole thing in view.  Also, I referred to a real, working class definition when I made this, but I didn't actually test or even try to compile it...

```
    class File_handle {
        FILE* fp;
    public:
        File_handle(const char* name, const char* mode) : fp(fopen(name, mode)) {}
        ~File_handle() { Close(); }
        operator FILE*() { return fp; } 
        void Close() { 
            if(fp) { fclose(fp);  fp = 0; }
        }

        File_handle& operator<< (const char* s) { fputs(s, fp); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (char c)    { fputc(c, fp); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (int x)     { fprintf(fp,"%d",x); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (unisgned x){ fprintf(fp,"%d",x); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (double x)  { fprintf(fp,"%f",x); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (float x)   { return operator<<(double(x)); }
        File_handle& operator<< (void*ptr)  { fprintf(fp,"%p",p); return *this; }
        File_handle& operator<< (bool x)    { return operator<<(int(x)); }
    };
```

This example omits a few basic types (like short, unsigned short, long long...), but you get the idea.

Additionally, some special and interesting overloads can be added.

What if somebody sticks another File_handle object into the chain?  If you add a way to support reading in addition to writing, maybe this would copy data from a reading-object's file into the writing-object's file.

Maybe you could do something special when a FILE* is thrown into the chain.

You might want to bring back the standard Library -- if the const char* overload isn't handling std::string objects like you want, maybe it could get handled separately:
        File_handle& operator << (const std::string& x) { ...... return *this; }

You can also add an overload which will handle all types not handled by any other overloads.  Template overloads will only handle types that none of the explicitly-typed versions can handle. So inside the class definition block, you might add:

```
    template <typename T>
    File_handle& operator << (const T& x) {
        return operator << ("what the hell is this crap?");
    }
```

(At least it avoids a compiling error)

By the way, in the examples, when overloads return operator<<(?), they are just passing work on to a different overload, based on whatever new type is passed in.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In any other class that you want to include on an opened file stream, just include after the using namespace declaration this: extern ofstream *name of the file*  and also remember to include the #include .

that should do it.